# How can I set access roles according to users ranks in YII 1.7x

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

I am new in Yii programming. So, I do not very well on the issues.
 Please help me to complete my projects. I have a users table like below attachment image.

[image: Sample Table Image Here]

I want to set different access role for different user's ranking (RANKS Colums).
Is it possible without creating modules?

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in your controllers, you could set a security check before every method, something like this:

Must be `admin` for access:

```
 if ($user->rank != 'admin')
 {
     return //NOT AUTHORIZED RESPONSE
 }
```

However, I would recommend removing that from the users table, and instead, create a `roles` table, and also, and pivot table for `users` and  `roles`, then you can have users with different roles. In in your User model, create a relationship between User and Role models. Much more complete access solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response. May you give me a well reference / example link for my easy understod? I am new learner of yii, sorry